# Recommended JSON parser in C?

Tags: c, json, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Way To Parse JSON in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673936/best-way-to-parse-json-in-c)

I need to parse, validate and query JSON data in a C application, and I am looking for recommendations for the best C JSON library.

The data will be input as strings (char* UTF-8 data), which I first need to validate to ensure the input is valid JSON, and then I will need to perform some simple queries (iterating over the data).

I do not need to produce JSON, I only need to consume it. I also would prefer a parser that will load the whole document into memory rather than a SAX-style parser.

Can anyone recommend a good library, or does anyone have any experience or had problems with libraries?

I have seen the list of libraries in C on JSON.org - are there any good libraries missing from this list?

My requirements are for a small library with as little code / runtime size as possible, and a permissive BSD/MIT style license, since my library will be embedded in other applications.

Thanks,

Marc

Answer (score 5):

I'm recommending [Jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/), which I find quite easy to use (and which loads the JSON in memory at once). However, I don't know well all the alternatives, and I don't have a working experience of all of them.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, is there any JSON library which doesn't uses dynamic allocations?

Comment: No, and I don't believe there can be one: JSON values could be arbitrarily large, so need to be heap allocated.

Answer (score 3):

I would choose [json-c](https://github.com/json-c/json-c) which is a fast and easy to use JSON parser written in C.

Comment: Have you had any experience with it? Are there any reasons why it is better/worse than the other options?

Comment: I have experience with json-c and only with json-c, so I can't compare against others. It is, for me, json-c just works. so I recommended it.

Comment: @JayElston Thanks. Fixed.