# Code generators and libraries for parsing JSON in C

Tags: c, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code generators and libraries for parsing JSON in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674575/code-generators-and-libraries-for-parsing-json-in-c)

I'd like to read JSON-encoded data into pre-defined C structs.  The data meet a well-known object structure.

As performance is crucial here, I really don't like to use libraries which generate a linked object tree.

Which library is suited for this purpose?  Are there alternative approaches, like code generators?

Comment: Hmm. They closed this one, nobody else voted to reopen the other one, and also they removed my comment recommending reopening. Sorry about all this :v( . Edit: Oh, it looks like a mod closed it just now after a reopen? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

For performance, I'd go with [libjson](http://projects.snarc.org/libjson/).  It's fast as hell and it doesn't generate it's own data structure.  It's a lot like a SAX parser for XML in that it delivers events like START_OBJECT, END_OBJECT, etc. to a callback function, so you can bind it to whatever data structure you want.

Comment: Wow, that looks promising. Thanks!