# How can i parse this json to get the strings and store them in variables?

Tags: c, json, cjson

How can i parse this json response after storing it as a char to get the strings and store them in variables? using any c library. Cjson probably because that's the one i am using to build the request..

```
{  

   "responseExitCode":"200",
   "message":"Account Created",
   "accountnumber":"58aa9f170c073",
   "accounttype":"Yea",
   "accountname":"Danstan Onyango"

}
```

Comment: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673936/parsing-json-using-c

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate of the linked question. OP wants to know how to use cJSON while the linked question is asking for recommendation of a library.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have that data in a `char *` you can parse them. Just read the [docs](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON). Its there.

```
char *my_json_string = "{ "responseExitCode" ...";

cJSON * root = cJSON_Parse(my_json_string);

char *message = cJSON_GetObjectItem(root, "message")->valuestring;
```

Comment: Worked. Helped me a lot. Thanks

Comment: @Danstan could you accept my answer?

Comment: Hey Sorry. Your answer was exactly what i needed. Working very well.